# Events not getting clicked in custom crm jquery full calendar

Tags: jquery, css

When I have resized the jquery calendar at that half of the click
event are not getting clicked and its working fine on IE but not works
on Firefox and chrome.

Comment: Please post your code to understand your problem in detail. A question without any code would be invalid sometimes in SO and is likely to get closed and downvoted.

Comment: how would you like us to help you? There could be 1000 reasons for something like this, based on your vague description. Without posting the (relevant parts of) the code and describing the problem in more detail (e.g. point out which elements are not clickable, and the exact differences in behaviour between browsers), we are just guessing. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            //h = screen.availHeight;
            w = screen.availWidth;
            $cal = $('#calendar');
            $cal.width(w);
            $modal = $('#myModal');
            $modal.width(w);
            //$modal.height(h);
            $(window).resize(function () {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', get_calendar_height());
            });
            fetchEventData();
            bindCalender();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                //options
                height: get_calendar_height

            });
        });
```